# wrapping startActivityForResult and onActivityResult in one function that returns result

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wait

I'm new to Android, and trying to create authentication function that will use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult and return result (in my case array of two strings - username and password from login screen).

Here's my code (returning null for username and password)

In main activity (calling authenticate() function):

```
public String user;
public String pass;

public void startAuth(Intent i)
{
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}

public String[] authenticate()
{
    String[] ret = new String[2];
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startAuth(i);

    ret[0] = i.getStringExtra("iUsername");
    ret[1] = i.getStringExtra("iPassword");

return ret;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data.getExtras().containsKey("iUsername"))
    {
        user = data.getStringExtra("iUsername");
        pass = data.getStringExtra("iPassword");
    }
}
```

In loginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_fill);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_fill);

    // Listening to Login Button
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            i.putExtra("iUsername", username.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("iPassword", password.getText().toString());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I understand that I need to somehow wait for the onActivityResult callback, but I've tried different solutions (using wait() and notify(), using singleton) but can't get it working...

I must wrap it, and not use it like this because I want to use the authenticate() function in much bigger code. Any solutions without using the above functions are also ok..

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should restructure the "much bigger code" to accept the result asynchronously.  You _could_ have that code run in a separate thread and use wait()/notify(), but that's definitely not ideal.

Comment: What is the error/exception thrown here?

Comment: Hi, I can't restructure the bigger code. I must deliver a "full mechanism" which returns the two strings as I mentioned, any use of wait and notify is ok as long as in the end I can wrap it all by authenticate(). About the seconde comment - there aren't any errors/exceptions, just getting the wrong results (because I'm not waiting for the event to finish...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public synchronized void startAuth(Intent i)
{
    m_intent = i;
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override 
        public void run()
        {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    startActivityForResult(m_intent, 1);
                }
            });     
        }           
    };

    thread.start();
}

// authenticate function
public String[] authenticate()
{
    String[] ret = new String[2];
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);

    startAuth(i);

    // waiting for login
    synchronized (lock) 
    {
        try 
        {
            lock.wait();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// writing results
    ret[0] = m_sUser;
    ret[1] = m_sPass;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are using `authenticate()` you aren't actually waiting for a response:

```
public void authenticate() // Changed return type to void
{
    //String[] ret = new String[2];
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startAuth(i);

    /*
     * This code does nothing, the Intent you want is in onActivityResult()

        ret[0] = i.getStringExtra("iUsername");
        ret[1] = i.getStringExtra("iPassword");
        return ret;
     */
}
```

You must break up your logic so that when `onActivityResult()` is called it resumes where `authenticate()` left off.  Understand you cannot resume in the middle of a method.
So you must call `authenticate()` at the end of one method and wherever you used `ret` must now be a new method which you call from `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Hi Sam, I've read you answer again - regarding your comment on breaking up the logic. Can't I call one method, wait for some flag\boolean\event handler which will come from onActivityResult(), and then use ret? If so - as I said, I want to wrap it all in one method (which will include all of those), again - thanks for your answer!

Comment: So any attempt to use `ret` will fail, that logic just doesn't work... and you can only access `user` and `pass` _after_ valid data comes back through `onActivityResult()`. You can use whatever approach you want as long as they adhere to those two rules.

Comment: ok, so I've figured it out - I've changed startAuth so it would run on UI thread, and made it synchronized + I've created an object "lock" and called in authenticate (between startAuth to ret assignments) to synchronized(lock) and lock.wait(), in onActivityResult I've added synchronized(lock) and lock.notify(), now everything is working as I wanted, and I managed to wrap it all to one function! 10x